# SharePoint requesting log-in on documents for members

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

For some reason SharePoint 2013 is asking members who are already logged in, to put in their credentails a second time when that member wants to open our Word documents.

What would be a cause for that? And how can I tell this document library or the Word docs in that document library **to not** request a 2nd log in call on documents if the user is already logged in?

using windows authentication

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of authentication do you have? Windows? FBA?

Comment: windows authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. Is `Enable Client Integration?` on for this SharePoint Web app (check in the Central Administration, "Application Management", "Manage web applications", select your Web app, "Authentication Providers" from the ribbon, "Default", last option of the dialog page).
2. Is your site in the Intranet zone of Internet Explorer?

Comment: yup, the issue was with enabling client integration.  thanks.